# Conditional using non-integer numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, conditionals, random-numbers

I am trying to generate fractals using affine transformations. 
I need to generate a random number in the interval (0,1), 
and depending on the value of this random number choose a 
function to calculate the coordinates of the point that I'll 
plot.

But the compiler is reporting an error I cannot figure out
how to solve.

Here's a code that describes the situation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);
% Here I generate a random number
    \pgfmathparse{rnd}
% I store the random number generated in memory 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\aleatorio}{\pgfmathresult}

    \ifthenelse{\aleatorio<0.5}{
        \node[red] at (5*rnd,5*rnd){\footnotesize\aleatorio};
    }{
        \node[blue] at (5*rnd,5*rnd){\footnotesize\aleatorio};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
%
\end{document}
```

When it comes to the line of the command `\ifthenelse`
to make the decision, it gives me an error message.

I think it is because `\ifnum` can compare only integer numbers.
To be honest, I am not sure. In any case, I need help 
to compare nonintegers (with decimal part) numbers and
then continue...

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it). There is no need for manual `<br/>`s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\aleatorio pt<0.5pt}}{true}{false}
```

A better implementation would be with PGF functions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);
  % generate a random number and store it
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\aleatorio}{rnd}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rndcolor}{ \aleatorio<0.5 ? "red" : "blue" }
  \node[\rndcolor] at (5*rnd,5*rnd){\footnotesize\aleatorio} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);
  % generate a random number and store it
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\aleatorio}{rnd}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rndcolor}{ \aleatorio<0.5 ? "red" : "blue" }
  \node[\rndcolor] at (5*rnd,5*rnd){\footnotesize\aleatorio} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);
  % generate a random number and store it
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\aleatorio}{rnd}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rndcolor}{ \aleatorio<0.5 ? "red" : "blue" }
  \node[\rndcolor] at (5*rnd,5*rnd){\footnotesize\aleatorio} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);
  % generate a random number and store it
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\aleatorio}{rnd}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rndcolor}{ \aleatorio<0.5 ? "red" : "blue" }
  \node[\rndcolor] at (5*rnd,5*rnd){\footnotesize\aleatorio} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]