# Have a new seed in pgfmath more often

Tags: pgfmath, random-numbers

I'm using pgfmath in my code since I need some randomness and I want the seed used for the randomness to be updated each time I compile. I read that pgfmath is updating the seed every minute, which is not enough for what I'm doing. Is there a way to force him to update every second or, even better, every millisecond?

Here is a toy example of code which prints randomly 4 elements in the list {one, two, three, four}

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{mylist}{{one}{two}{three}{four}}
\pgfmathrandomitem\elem{mylist}\elem\  
\pgfmathrandomitem\elem{mylist}\elem\   
\pgfmathrandomitem\elem{mylist}\elem\  
\pgfmathrandomitem\elem{mylist}\elem
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a simple code example to play with? If you use `pdflatex` then maybe `\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfrandomseed}` might do.

Comment: I added a toy example. I' compiling with latex and not with pdflatex and I would prefer continuing so.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you use `pdflatex` or LuaLaTeX, then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\test}{rand}\test

\end{document}
```

will pick a random seed each time. With XeLaTeX there's nothing similar. The value of `\pdfrandomseed` doesn't change during a run, though.

Comment: Thanks, but as said above, I would prefer to use LaTeX if possible. If not, I will have to adapt and use pdfLaTeX

Comment: @ocalex86 You *are* using `pdflatex` also when running `latex` for DVI output.

Comment: Oh, sorry, then. I just tried, it works well. Thanks a lot !

Comment: For LuaLaTeX this (now) requires just `\randomseed` instead of `\pdfrandomseed`.