# Why do I need to wait about 30 seconds or more to generate a new set of questions in this code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, random-numbers

> This is a follow-up question to this question:
>   [Generate exam from a question bank?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174872/generate-exam-from-a-question-bank)

In the following code by @Werner, I am curious to know **why do I need to wait about 30 seconds or more to generate a new set of questions?** What happens during these seconds? Why `LaTeX` needs this time?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}% Just for this example
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bankA.tex}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 1
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 2
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 3
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 4
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 5
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 6
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 7
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 8
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 9
\end{questionblock}
\begin{questionblock}
Question 10
\end{questionblock}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{catchfile,environ,tikz}

\makeatletter% Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109619/5764
\def\declarenumlist#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname{#3}%
  \count@\@ne
  \loop
    \expandafter\edef
    \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\count@\endcsname
      {\the\count@}
    \ifnum\count@<#3\relax
    \advance\count@\@ne
  \repeat}
\def\prunelist#1{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname
          {\the\numexpr\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname-1\relax}
  \count@\pgfmath@randomtemp 
  \loop
    \expandafter\global\expandafter\let
    \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\count@\expandafter\endcsname
    \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\numexpr\count@+1\relax\endcsname
    \ifnum\count@<\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname\relax
      \advance\count@\@ne
  \repeat}
\makeatother

% Define how each questionblock should be handled
\newcounter{questionblock}
\newcounter{totalquestions}
\NewEnviron{questionblock}{}%

\newcommand{\randomquestionsfrombank}[2]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\bank}{#1}{}% Read the entire bank of questions into \bank
  \setcounter{totalquestions}{0}% Reset total questions counters  ***
  \RenewEnviron{questionblock}{\stepcounter{totalquestions}}% Count every question  ***
  \bank% Process file  ***
  \declarenumlist{uniquequestionlist}{1}{\thetotalquestions}% list from 1 to totalquestions inclusive.
  \setcounter{totalquestions}{#2}% Start the count-down
  \RenewEnviron{questionblock}{%
    \stepcounter{questionblock}% Next question
    \ifnum\value{questionblock}=\randomquestion 
      \par% Start new paragraph
      \BODY% Print question
    \fi
  }%
  \foreach \uNiQueQ in {1,...,#2} {% Extract #2 random questions
    \setcounter{questionblock}{0}% Start fresh with question block counter
    \pgfmathrandomitem\randomquestion{uniquequestionlist}% Grab random question from list
    \xdef\randomquestion{\randomquestion}% Make random question available globally
    \prunelist{uniquequestionlist}% Remove picked item from list
    \bank% Process file
  }}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,6} {
    \bigskip
    \randomquestionsfrombank{bankA.tex}{6}
  }
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

By the way, my own file is in Persian and I'm using `xelatex` if it helps.

Comment: Using  `\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}` seems to make it change whenever you compile.

Comment: @Watson: How to use this command?

Comment: Just write it before \begin{document} (but after \usepackage{catchfile,environ,tikz}).

Comment: For LuaLaTeX, it requires just `\randomseed` instead of `\pdfrandomseed` as said [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144621/have-a-new-seed-in-pgfmath-more-often#comment936139_144623).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each pseudo-random number generated using [PGF](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) uses a seed that is generated by `\pgfmathsetseed`. The [PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) mentions the following about this macro:

> ```
> \pgfmathsetseed{<integer>}
> ```
>
> Explicitly sets the seed for the pseudo-random number generator. By default it is set to the value of `\time` x `\year`.

Well, it's obvious that the only influence in terms of changing a pseudo-random number would stem from `\time`, since it's more likely to change before `\year` does ;)

So, what is `\time`? According to [TeX by Topic](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf) (section **33.5 Time**, p 263):

> TeX has four parameters, `\year`, `\month`, `\day`, and `\time`, that tell the time when the current job started. After this, the parameters are not updated. The user can change them at any time.
>
> All four parameters are integers; the `\time` parameter gives the number of minutes
>   since midnight that the current job started.

Note that `\time` represents only minutes (since midnight). As such, it'll only change every minute (which falls within "every 30 seconds or more"; you may just have noticed this behaviour around a minute-mark).

<sub>To see what `\time` looks like, add `\showthe\time` to your code and check the `.log`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and great answer. The only thing is that when I add `showthe\time` to my code, it gives me this warning: `LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file ./bankA.tex'.\openout15 = bankA.tex'.`

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan: The warning you mention stems from the use of the [`filecontents` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) which allows overwriting of existing files (and always warns about it). `\showthe\time` should show up in your `.log` showing (say) `1419` for `11:39PM`.

Comment: Wouldn't using `\pdfuniformdeviate` relieve the OP from the issue?

Comment: @egreg: Yes, it should. I'll mock up a solution using `\pdfuniformdeviate` and update my answer here (otherwise this question might become obsolete).

Comment: @egreg Would you please show where to type `\pdfuniformdeviate` to get a random seed each compilation?

Comment: @Diaa Just don't use `\pgfmathsetseed`, so something “random” will be chosen as the seed.