# How to randomly and differently select questions from their bank each compilation?

Tags: exam, pgfmath

Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174962/2288), the following document, many times, doesn't change the output each time I compile it. The output may change after three or four times I recompile the document.

So, how to change the randomization mechanism to make the output different from its previous version each time I compile the document?

```
\documentclass{exam}


\usepackage[randomize]{exam-randomizechoices}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{bankA.tex}
    \begin{questionblock}
        \question[5] What is the result of $1+1$?
        \begin{randomizechoices}
            \choice 1
            \CorrectChoice 2
            \choice 3
            \choice 4
        \end{randomizechoices}
    \end{questionblock}
    \begin{questionblock}
        \question[5] What is the result of $2+1$?
        \begin{randomizechoices}
            \choice 11
            \CorrectChoice 3
            \choice 31
            \choice 14
        \end{randomizechoices}
    \end{questionblock}
    \begin{questionblock}
        \question[5] What is the result of $3+1$?
        \begin{randomizechoices}
            \choice 111
            \CorrectChoice 4
            \choice 31
            \choice 411
        \end{randomizechoices}
    \end{questionblock}
    \begin{questionblock}
        \question[5] What is the result of $4+1$?
        \begin{randomizechoices}
            \choice 111
            \CorrectChoice 5
            \choice 113
            \choice 114
        \end{randomizechoices}
    \end{questionblock}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{catchfile,environ,tikz}

\makeatletter% Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109619/5764
\def\declarenumlist#1#2#3{%
    \expandafter\edef\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname{#3}%
    \count@\@ne
    \loop
    \expandafter\edef
    \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\count@\endcsname
    {\the\count@}
    \ifnum\count@<#3\relax
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \repeat}
\def\prunelist#1{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname
    {\the\numexpr\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname-1\relax}
    \count@\pgfmath@randomtemp 
    \loop
    \expandafter\global\expandafter\let
    \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\count@\expandafter\endcsname
    \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\numexpr\count@+1\relax\endcsname
    \ifnum\count@<\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname\relax
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \repeat}
\makeatother

% Define how each questionblock should be handled
\newcounter{questionblock}
\newcounter{totalquestions}
\NewEnviron{questionblock}{}%

\newcommand{\randomquestionsfrombank}[2]{%
    \CatchFileDef{\bank}{#1}{}% Read the entire bank of questions into \bank
    \setcounter{totalquestions}{0}% Reset total questions counters  ***
    \RenewEnviron{questionblock}{\stepcounter{totalquestions}}% Count every question  ***
    \bank% Process file  ***
    \declarenumlist{uniquequestionlist}{1}{\thetotalquestions}% list from 1 to totalquestions inclusive.
    \setcounter{totalquestions}{#2}% Start the count-down
    \RenewEnviron{questionblock}{%
        \stepcounter{questionblock}% Next question
        \ifnum\value{questionblock}=\randomquestion 
        \par% Start new paragraph
        \BODY% Print question
        \fi
    }%
    \foreach \uNiQueQ in {1,...,#2} {% Extract #2 random questions
        \setcounter{questionblock}{0}% Start fresh with question block counter
        \pgfmathrandomitem\randomquestion{uniquequestionlist}% Grab random question from list
        \xdef\randomquestion{\randomquestion}% Make random question available globally
        \prunelist{uniquequestionlist}% Remove picked item from list
        \bank% Process file
}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{questions}
        \randomquestionsfrombank{bankA.tex}{2}
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just wait for a minute? See [tikz pgf - Why do I need to wait about 30 seconds or more to generate a new set of questions in this code? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218018/why-do-i-need-to-wait-about-30-seconds-or-more-to-generate-a-new-set-of-question?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @user202729 you are right. I will close this question as it has an answer somewhere else.