# Random compile-time document style

Tags: pgfmath, documentclass-writing, random

I am trying to create a document class with random style attributes, determined at compilation time. Random attributes would ideally include:

- Margins
- Line spacing
- Font selection

For my particular use case, in-document references are not typically useful/a design constraint, so there's no first-order need to worry about layout being consistent across compilations.

I attempted to use `\pgfmathrandomitem` in a new `.cls` file, as follows:

```
% randocls.cls
\LoadClass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{marginmargins}{{0.0}{0.25}{0.5}{0.75}}
\pgfmathrandomitem{\marginns}{marginmargins}

% none of the following work...
% (the implied margins are different; this is MWE so nbd)

% Case 1:
\usepackage[margin={\marginns}in]{geometry}

% Case 2:
% \addtolength{\topmargin}{{\marginns}in}

% Case 3:
% \let\rmarginns{\marginns}
% \addtolength{\topmargin}{{\rmarginns}in}
```

---

Under **Case 1**:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg")
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.1007 \ProcessOptionsKV[p]{Gm}
                               %
```

Under **Case 2**:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.23 \addtolength{\topmargin}{{\marginns}in}
```

Under **Case 3**:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.30 \let\rmarginns{\marginns
                             }
```

---

My best guess is that the problem relates to when `pgfmathrandomitem` can actually yield a random item, but I am in over my head. Is there a way to work around this, or another randomization mechanism that will allow randomization in the document header?

Comment: Note that the random seed is based on the minutes of the system clock. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144621/have-a-new-seed-in-pgfmath-more-often if you want to have a new random seed more often.

Comment: @Marijn this is helpful. I'm going to be using XeTeX for font selection, so the linked solution will not work. However, outside of testing it's really not a big deal to have the random seed changed only once per minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some issue with expansion and groups - this is always tricky in LaTeX. A solution here is to put the unit in the list:

```
% randocls.cls
\LoadClass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{marginmargins}{{0.0in}{0.25in}{0.5in}{0.75in}}
\pgfmathrandomitem{\marginns}{marginmargins}

% Case 1:
\usepackage[margin=\marginns]{geometry}
```

```
\documentclass{randocls}
\begin{document}
margin: \marginns
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, this solves the margins issue; not as difficult as I thought! I'm going to make sure it solves the other issues (spacing, font selection) before accepting.

Comment: The one note to add: because I would like to select *different* left-right and top-bottom margins, it's necessary to select two different random lengths. Due to pgf's innards, I need to select a random margin, `edef` it to a temporary variable, then select another random margin; otherwise, the same random margin is returned twice.