# "Countryball" comic with TikZ. How to shade a 3D object with different stripes on it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, fun

*Countryball* (if I'm not mistaken originally *Polandball*) is a web comic versing on crude political jokes, some of which I find hilarious. In some sense, the idea is analogous to the [spherical cow simplification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow) The protagonists are countries represented by figures tinged by the colors of the respective flag. These figures are spheres, ellipsoids or egg-like objects (excepting Israel, Singapore, Kazakhstan and –obviously– Nepal). Moreover there are some (perfectly questionable) "rules" like:

> 1. Spheres cannot be perfect
> 2. No limbs, no pupils …
> 3. No lines between the different colors of a flag, etc.

Countryballs look like [this](http://static.fjcdn.com/large/pictures/c9/9c/c99cf6_3723440.jpg). Long story short, I was wondering if it is possible to implement this with TikZ. So here is my first attempt. I based on the code [of this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines/49961#49961) in order to make the eyes of this ball associated to a (hopefully unexisent) flag:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{penciline}{initial}{
    \state{initial}[width=+\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance,
    auto corner on length=1mm,]{
        \pgfpathcurveto%
        {% From
            \pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}
                      {\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
        }
        {%  Control 1
        \pgfmathrand
        \pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}{1pt}}
                    {\pgfqpoint{-\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect
                     \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}%
                               {\pgfmathresult\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
                    }
        }
        {%TO 
        \pgfpointadd{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}{\pgfpoint{.3pt}{.4pt}}
        }
    }
    \state{final}{}
}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=penciline, decorate]
%\draw (-2, 1.5) rectangle (2, -1.5);
\begin{scope}
\clip (-0.8, 0) ellipse (1 and 3);
%\clip ( 1, 0) ellipse (1 and 4);
\clip ( 0.5, 0) circle (1);
\fill[color=yellow!85!black] (-2,1.5)
rectangle (2,-1.5);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip (1.8, 0) ellipse (1 and 3);
%\clip ( 1, 0) ellipse (1 and 4);
\clip ( 0.5, 0) circle (1);
\fill[color=red!75!black] (-2,1.5)
rectangle (2,-1.5);
\end{scope}
    \draw[
      decoration={random steps,segment length=.3cm,amplitude=.05cm},
      decorate,
      rounded corners=.13cm, ultra thick
    ] (.5, 0) circle (.95);
   % right eye 
   \draw[decorate,fill=white, thick] (0.85,.23) ellipse (.22 and .08);
   % left eye 
   \draw[decorate,fill=white, thick] (0.02,.23) ellipse (.22 and .08);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

While it is not expected to obtain beautiful countryballs, my code is not satisfying at all. It produces this

[image]

As you can see, the circle doesn't close.

Question: Could somebody fix this circle and produce a more realistic ball?

**3D Implementation**

I first tried in 3D. The only thing I achieve is the "non-being" spherical. This is the code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\pgfmathsetseed{42}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[ball color=red,decoration={random steps,segment length=.7cm,amplitude=.1cm},decorate,rounded corners=.3cm,ultra thick] (0,0) circle (8.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Question:** How to independently color the hemispheres (either "vertically" or "horizontally"), or more generally, how to color stripes (usually 3) of different colors?

[image]

Comment: The intention was to specifically miss the closing to emphasize hand drawing :p

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, the trick here is to use a `path picture` and clip the path for each strip and then shade the *entire* path picture area letting the clipping "do all the work". Everything can then be tied up in keys.

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing}
\newcount\countryballcolorcount
\newif\ifcountryballhorizontal
\tikzset{sketch/.style={%
  rounded corners=.15cm, 
  ultra thick,
  decoration={%
    random steps,
    segment length=0.7cm,
    amplitude=0.1cm,
    pre=lineto, pre length=0.1cm,
    post=lineto, post length=.1cm
  },
  decorate},
  country ball colors/.store in=\countryballcolors,
  country ball horizontal/.is if=countryballhorizontal,
  country ball/.style={#1,
    path picture={%
      \countryballcolorcount=0\relax
      \csname pgfutil@for\endcsname\c:=\countryballcolors\do{%
       \advance\countryballcolorcount by1\relax
      }%
      \foreach \c [count=\i from 0] in \countryballcolors{
        \begin{scope}
          \ifnum\i>0
            % Clip the part of the picture to be shaded.
            \ifcountryballhorizontal
              \clip (path picture bounding box.south west) --
                ($(path picture bounding box.north west)!{\i/\countryballcolorcount}!(path picture bounding box.south west)$)    
                decorate {% sketch is still the prevailing decoration
                  -- ($(path picture bounding box.north east)!{\i/\countryballcolorcount}!(path picture bounding box.south east)$)
                }
                --  (path picture bounding box.south east) -- cycle;
            \else
              \clip (path picture bounding box.south east) --
                ($(path picture bounding box.south west)!{\i/\countryballcolorcount}!(path picture bounding box.south east)$)    
                decorate {% sketch is still the prevailing decoration
                  -- ($(path picture bounding box.north west)!{\i/\countryballcolorcount}!(path picture bounding box.north east)$)
                }
                --  (path picture bounding box.north east) -- cycle;
            \fi
          \fi
          % Shade the *entire* picture
          \path [shading=ball, ball color=\c]
            (path picture bounding box.south west)
            rectangle
            (path picture bounding box.north east);
       \end{scope}
    }
  }
}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [sketch, country ball={country ball colors={yellow!85!black, white, red!75!black}}]
  (0,0) circle [radius=5];
\draw [sketch, country ball={country ball horizontal, country ball colors={yellow!85!black, white, red!75!black}}]
  (0,-11) circle [radius=5];
\draw [sketch, country ball={country ball colors={yellow!85!black, white, red!75!black, green!50!black, blue!75!black}}]
  (0,-22) circle [radius=5];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]