# List of all modules in ConTeXt

Tags: context, big-list

Is there a comprehensive updated list of modules currently maintained? The [ConTeXt wiki page for modules](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modules) provides some but I am not sure if it is updated and which ones would be obsolete. It would be nice if the ConTeXt users here at TeX.SX can highlight the modules they use the most and provide some description of there usage.

Comment: should this be a community wiki with one module per answer?

Comment: @Aditya +1 I vote to that. It would be nice to have a comprehensive list of modules and their possible usage. This can help other newcomers like myself to the ConTeXt community.

Comment: @Aditya: +1 from me, too.

Comment: I described all the modules that I use frequently; there are other modules that I have written/contributed to (e.g., mathsets, simpleslides, gantt) but don't use these days.

Comment: @Aditya This is wonderful. Quick question: if I run `first-setup.bat --modules=all`, does it make sense and does it download the ones you have spoken about here?

Comment: @azetina: all except the overviewpage module, which hasn't been officially released yet (need time to write a decent documentation).

Answer (score 10):

### Filter Module

Available on [contextgarden](http://modules.contextgarden.net/filter), [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/context-filter), or [github](https://github.com/adityam/filter/).

#### Documentation

[github](https://github.com/adityam/filter/blob/master/README.md)

#### Short description

This module allows you to *filter* the content of an environment through an external program. I routinely use this to create graphs in documents, where the graphs are generated from a scientific computing software (Matlab, Mathematica, or Python).

The module takes care of all the book-keeping of creating temporary files and caching the results (so that subsequent runs are fast).

#### Example

The example from a presentation shows graphs generated by Mathematica code written as part of a ConTeXt document. The Mathematica code is also included in the PDF file as an attachment.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

### Visualcounter module

Available on [contextgarden](http://modules.contextgarden.net/visualcounter) or [github](https://github.com/adityam/visualcounter).

#### Documentation

[github](https://github.com/adityam/visualcounter/raw/master/visualcounter.pdf)

#### Short description

This module gives a *visual representation* of any ConTeXt counter. It comes with a few predefined styles, and provides an interface to easily add new styles. See the documentation for details. I use this to show page numbers and lecture numbers in slides and to add a bit of a glitter to otherwise dull presentation.

#### Example

The example below from a presentation shows the visual counter module in action. The page number (2 out of 7) is displayed on the lower right and the lecture number (4 out of 5) is to its left.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### Vim module

Available on [contextgarden](http://modules.contextgarden.net/vim), [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/context-vim), and [github](https://github.com/adityam/filter/).

#### Documentation

[github](https://github.com/adityam/filter/blob/master/vim-README.md)

#### Short description

The example below from a presentation shows syntax highlighted Java code.

[image]

This module uses a vimL script to provide syntax highlighting for the 500+ programming languages that the Vim editor supports. The module uses the filter module in the background. I routinely use it to include syntax highlighted code snippets in my documents.

#### Example

Answer (score 4):

### Overviewpage module

Available on [github](https://github.com/adityam/context-overviewpage)

#### Documentation

[Blog post](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/announcing-the-overview-module/)

#### Short description

This module provides an overview screen at the end of the presentation, showing the first page of each section. This may be used as a quick reference to jump to specific locations on the presentation while answering audience questions.

#### Example

The example below shows the overview page of one of my presentations.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### MP sketch

This is not a formal module, but a metapost environment that I use, so I thought that I'd mention this as well.

Available on [github](https://github.com/adityam/mp-sketch).

#### Documentation

[TeX.SX answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96674/323)

#### Description

This module is inspired by [the question to simulate hand drawn lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39296/323). I occasionally use this to give an informal looks to figures used in presentations.

#### Example

Here is one figure drawn using mp-sketch.

[image]

Sometimes, I also use a variation of this approach and draw the same line multiple times by randomizing the end points.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Visual module and MetaPost library dum

Part of ConTeXt code

#### Documentation

[This Way Magazine](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/magazines/mag-0007.pdf)

#### Short description

This module provides macros to fake text and images. This is useful when you are creating a new layout/style and want to check how it looks in different scenarios.

#### Example

```
\usemodule[visual]
\useMPlibrary[dum]

\setupindenting[medium,yes]
\setupwhitespace[medium]

\startsetups head
  \definecolor[fakerulecolor]     [darkred]
\stopsetups

\setuphead[subject]
          [alternative=middle, style=\tfc, color=red, before={\bgroup \setups{head}}, after=\egroup\blank]

\setupcaption[style={\switchtobodyfont[8pt]}]

\starttext

\subject{\fakewords{3}{5}}

\startplacefigure[location={right}, title={\fakewords{8}{20}}]
  \externalfigure[dummy][height=3cm, width=5cm]
\stopplacefigure

\fakewords{20}{30} 

\startformula
  \fakeformula
\stopformula

\fakewords{50}{100} 

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## metaducks module

Available on [ConTeXt Garden](https://modules.contextgarden.net/cgi-bin/module.cgi/ruid=70738084/action=view/id=105) and [GitHub](https://github.com/JairoAdelRio/context-metaducks) for ConTeXt MkIV and ConTeXt LMTX.

### Documentation

In [Spanish (GitHub)](https://github.com/JairoAdelRio/context-metaducks/blob/main/metaducks-manual-es.pdf) and [English (GitHub)](https://github.com/JairoAdelRio/context-metaducks/blob/main/metaducks-manual-en.pdf)

### Short description

A fork of [TikZducks](https://github.com/samcarter/tikzducks) rewritten using MetaPost/Metafun to work without dependencies on PGF and integrating with ConTeXt machinery better. Additionally, there's a `\setupducks` handler to set global options for ducks.

For those who don't know about TikZducks and, as the name suggest, this module allows you to draw funny and cute rubber ducks with various garments, hairdos and accessories. Some additional accessories have been added.

### Examples

```
\usecolors[svg]
\usemodule[metaducks]
\starttext
\startTEXpage
%\duck is an alias for \ducks
\duck
    [blush=yes,
    lei=yes,
    parrot=yes,
    blushcolor=deeppink]
\ducks
    [pupilcolor=dodgerblue,
    mug=yes,
    bodycolor=pink,
    grumpy=yes,
    peakedcap=yes]
\ducks
    [bodycolor=black,
    pupilcolor=red,
    devil=yes,
    laughing=yes,
    billcolor=red]
\stopTEXpage
\startTEXpage
\dostepwiserecurse\zerocount\plusten\plusone{%
\begingroup
\definecolor[rainbow][h=\luaexpr{36*\recurselevel},s=1,v=1]
\ducks
    [unitsize=5mm,
    bodycolor=rainbow,
    signpost=yes,
    signtext={\bf\os\recurselevel}]%
    \space%
\endgroup}
\stopTEXpage
\startTEXpage
\dorecurse\plusten{\randomduck[unitsize=5mm]}
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

[image]

[image]

[image]