# Simulating hand-drawn on curve lines, make a cycle AND fill it if necessary

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

Reading this question : [Simulating hand-drawn lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines) and following Percusse's idea I tried this :

[image]
[image]

But is it possible to "hide" the multido code in a style command and pass the parameters throu `keys`. By the way, for a `step` of 0.01, there is 101 marks but for a `step` of 0.2 there is only 50, and the line doesn't go to the end ?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={markings,
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step .01 with {
\node at (0,.3pt*rand) [coordinate,
name=mark-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}]
{};}}]
\draw [help lines] grid (3,2);
\draw [postaction={decorate},help lines] (0,0) -- (3,1) arc (0:180:1.5 and 1);
\draw[smooth] [red] (mark-1)
    \foreach \i in {2,...,101} {-- (mark-\i) } ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={markings,
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step .01 with {
\node at (0,.4pt*rand) [coordinate,
name=mark-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}]
{};}}]
\draw [help lines] grid (3,2);
\path [postaction={decorate}] (0,0) -- (3,1) arc (0:180:1.5 and 1) -- cycle ;
\draw[smooth,red,fill=red!15] (mark-1)
    \foreach \i in {2,...,101} {-- (mark-\i) } ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you request. Probably not the best.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{%
  hand drawn/random interval/.initial = 1pt,
  hand drawn/step/.initial = 0.05,
  hand drawn with markings/.style = {%
   decoration={%
    markings,
    mark = between positions 0 and 1 step \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hand drawn/step} with {%
      \edef\SequenceNumber{%
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}}%
      \coordinate (mark-\SequenceNumber) at
      (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hand drawn/random interval}*rand);
      \ifnum\SequenceNumber>1\relax
      \draw[#1] (mark-\number\numexpr\SequenceNumber-1\relax) 
        -- 
        (mark-\SequenceNumber);
      \fi},
    },
    decorate},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [help lines] grid (3,2);
  \draw [hand drawn with markings = {red}] (0,0) -- (3,1) arc (0:180:1.5 and 1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but I just realized that you can not make a `cycle` and fill it with this methode.

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}` with `random steps` does it as well. I've missed it.