# Is possible give the handwrite aspect to other thing?, as ncline, rectangles,... in PStricks?

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

Viewing doc, I realized that there is an option (similar to linestyle=¿handwrited? ;-) ) to simulate handwriting.

Is possible give this aspect to other elements as triangles, poligons, curves, nclines,...  ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can remerber the years I used PsTricks, it wasn't possible because there was no `linestyle` for this.

In `Metapost` I used for straight lines :

```
% Ligne à main levée
% a,b sont les extrémités
% torture controle la déformation
def mainlevee(expr a,b,torture) =
    (a{dir (angle(b-a)+torture)}..{dir (angle(b-a)+torture)}b) enddef ;
```

With `Tikz` :

(and more here [Simulating hand-drawn lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines))

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{handmade/.style={rounded corners=.1pt,decoration={random steps,segment length=1pt,amplitude=.25pt},decorate}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] grid (3,2);
\draw [handmade,fill=red!15,very thin]
(0,0) -- (3,1) arc (0:180:1.5 and 1) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]