# Drawing a brush stroke like outline

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to reproduce the following picture with TikZ:

[image]

Which is basically a circle with a variable width outline (the red line in the pic) that looks like a brush stroke. Can someone kindly give me a pointer to where to start?

Comment: Have a look at here: [simulating hand drawn lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines). This should be a start.

Comment: You should start with an MWE! Define the colours, the size, the blue circle. Tell us what you have tried so far. Like this you will get an answer much quicker.

Comment: Would be easier, I think, in `metapost` than `tikz`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "poor man" solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node(a)[circle,fill=blue,minimum size=3cm]{};

\draw[line width=1pt,red,line cap=rounded] (a.180)to[bend left=45](a.90);
\draw[line width=1pt,red] (a.170)to[bend left=45](a.80);
\draw[line width=1.5pt,red] (a.160)to[bend left=45](a.70);
\draw[line width=2pt,red] (a.150)to[bend left=45](a.60);
\draw[line width=2.5pt,red] (a.140)to[bend left=45](a.50);
\draw[line width=3pt,red] (a.130)to[bend left=45](a.40);
\draw[line width=3.5pt,red] (a.120)to[bend left=45](a.30);
\draw[line width=4pt,red] (a.110)to[bend left=45](a.20);
\draw[line width=4.5pt,red] (a.100)to[bend left=45](a.10);
\draw[line width=5pt,red,line cap=round] (a.90)to[bend left=45](a.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use a `foreach` loop to make the code prettier and/or add more steps so to have a smoother width increase.

You still need to implement the brush effect.