# How can I reproduce the chemmacros logo style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemmacros

I'd like to reproduce the chemmacros logo style, as seen in chemmacros [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chemmacros/chemmacros_en.pdf)

I checked the source .tex file, but the logo is loaded from another pdf "chemmacros-logo.pdf" that is nowhere to be found into TeX Live.

Since I'm assuming the logo is drawn with TikZ or something, is its code available somewhere?

Comment: Why not asking @cgnieder? He can often be found in the chat room?

Comment: @percusse Yes, I could, but maybe this may also be of general interest? If not I'll ask him in chat.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise on what you define as *logo style*? All i see is the name written in bold and a dark red.

Comment: @Johannes_B I mean the style of the formula below the email. That formula is the "chemmacros-logo" according to the .tex file.

Comment: Just noted it myself, good question ;-)

Comment: You could start by using the [same font](http://www.dafont.com/augie.font) :)

Comment: @Harald thanks, that would be necessary I guess :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[image]

Here's the code I used to produce the “logo”. The font is [Augie](http://www.dafont.com/augie.font), the redox arrows are drawn with `chemmacros`' own macros, the lines are decorated with [@percusse's `pencilline` decoration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49961/) (compile two times with `xelatex`):

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}

% credits:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49961/
\pgfdeclaredecoration{pencilline}{initial}{
  \state{initial}[
    width=+\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance,
    auto corner on length=1mm
  ]{
    \pgfpathcurveto%
      {% From
        \pgfqpoint
          {\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}
          {\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
      }
      {%  Control 1
        \pgfmathrand
        \pgfpointadd
          {\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}{0pt}}
          {%
            \pgfqpoint
              {-\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}%
              {\pgfmathresult\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
          }
      }
      {%TO 
        \pgfpointadd
          {\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}
          {\pgfpoint{1pt}{1pt}}
      }
  }
  \state{final}{}
}
\tikzset{pencil/.style={decorate,decoration=pencilline}}
\begin{document}
   \ch[font-spec={Augie}]{
     2 "\OX{o1,\ox{0,Na}}" + "\OX{r1,\ox{0,Cl}}" {}2
     ->
     2 "\OX{o2,\ox{+1,Na}}" {}+ + 2 "\OX{r2,\ox{-1,Cl}}" {}-
   }
   \redox(o1,o2)[red,pencil,-cf]{%
     \small\ch[font-spec={[Color=red]Augie},math-space=.3em]{$-$ 2 e-}}
   \redox(r1,r2)[blue,pencil,-cf][-1]{%
     \small\ch[font-spec={[Color=blue]Augie},math-space=.3em]{$+$ 2 e-}}
\end{document}
```

---

A possible improvement: adding

```
\setchemformula{ arrow-style = pencil }
```

will also draw the reaction arrow with the `pencilline` decoration. I might add this to the next version.

[image]

Comment: OK, that does it. I gotta polish this thing. It's poisoning even very sound packages :P

Comment: @percusse: sir I read `penicillin` instead of `pencilline`. `:P`

Comment: @Paulo me too :) not completely unfitting for a chemical picture...