# How do I produce the text displayed on the banner of this website?

Tags: math-mode, languages, chemistry, physics

This question is for interest purposes, rather than a problem which I have to be solved.

How does one produce the equations and text displayed on the banner of this website? Here is a screenshot of the banner to show you.

[image: StackExchange TeX Banner]

It maybe difficult to see, so I played with the brightness and contrast:

[image: Modified]

I believe I have figured out some of them.

- Maxwell Electrostatics Equation for EMF Induction

For which the LaTeX code is:

```
\[
\oint_{\partial S}\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{l}=-\frac{\partial\Phi_{B,S}}{\partial t}
\]
```

And produces:
[image: Maxwell]

- Euler's Identity for Complex Numbers

For which the LaTeX code is:

```
\[
\mathrm{e}^{x+\mathrm{i}y}=\mathrm{e}^x(\cos(y)+\mathrm{i}\sin(y))
\]
```

And produces:
[image: complex]

Comment: easy to do with `tikz`

Comment: See the background image: http://cdn.sstatic.net/tex/img/sprites-extra.svg?v=891c6278e498

Comment: Euler formula uses Euler fonts: `\usepackage{eulervm}` and

`\[
e^{x+ iy}= e^{x}(\cos y +i\sin y )
\]`

Comment: Upper left is part of the Ring inscription, ¿no? I think it's in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13024/38080

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Do you wanna sum up the main points? Isn't there a meta question dealing with this?

Comment: @Johannes_B OK. Thanks. I will provide an answer, but later since I am kind of busy right now.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered, to some extent, across the main site as well as [Meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com).

From Meta, see the post relating to [Site Design Ideas (updated with mockup)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/638/5764) which formed part of the site graduation.

From the main site, see how to [Recreate the sphere in TeX.SX logo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251734/5764).

Answer (score 0):

For the last part, for the chemical equation, you can find it right there: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/oxidation-and-reduction/

Comment: That's probably how the reaction was produced for [tex.se]'s background. In practice I'd nowadays use `chemmacros` (see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196515/5049)