# How to change the color of the oxidation numbers in chemmacros?

Tags: color, chemmacros

I would like to change the color of the oxidation numbers in some reactions like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\let\chold\ch % necesario para que ch ponga bien las flechas
\renewcommand\ch[1]{%
    \catcode`<=12
    \catcode`>=12
    \chold{#1}%
    \catcode`<=\active
    \catcode`>=\active
}
\chemsetup{
  formula = {chemformula} ,
  modules = {redox} 
}
\chemsetup[redox]{
roman = false ,
explicit-sign = true ,
pos = top
}
\begin{document}
\ch{"\ox{5,N}" O3^- + 1 e- + 2 H+ <=> "\ox{4,N}" O2 + H2O}
\end{document}
```

[image: The reaction i want to change color of the oxidation numbers]

I use chemmacros (ox) to write the oxidation numbers, but there is no color option.
Is there any way to change only the oxidations numbers? Thanks in advance

Comment: I need \catcode to write the arrows, in spanish "<" and ">" are inactive

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196515

Comment: Thanks Ross. That link works fine if you want to change color of the arrows of "OX", they connect oxidant and reductant semiequations, but it not use diferent colors for the oxidation numbers

Comment: If you disable parsing you should be able to use `\color{+5}` or similar. (I guess this is worth a feature request on chemmacros' github)

Comment: disable parsing ? Sorry but i am newcomer in latex and i dont know how to do it. I tried with  \textcolor{red}{5} , but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

#### update 2020/03/09

Using the newest versions of `chemmacros` and `chemformula` you

1. can use the option `redox/format` to add the color and
2. don't need your workaround any more:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{chemmacros}[2020/03/07]
\usepackage{chemformula}[2020/03/07]

\chemsetup{
  formula = chemformula ,
  modules = redox ,
  redox/roman = false ,
  redox/explicit-sign = true ,
  redox/pos = top ,
  redox/format = \textcolor{red}
}
\begin{document}

\ch{"\ox{5,N}" O3^- + 1 e- + 2 H+ <=> "\ox{4,N}" O2 + H2O}

<<Test>>

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Original Answer, 2020/03/06

For the time being the only viable possibility is to disable the parsing of the oxidation numbers (note that then the option `redox/roman` and `redox/explicit-sign` don't have any effect…). When the parsing is disabled you can just use `\textcolor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\chemsetup{
  formula = chemformula ,
  modules = redox ,
  redox/parse = false ,
  redox/pos = top
}

\begin{document}

\ch{"\ox{\textcolor{red}{+5},N}" O3^-}

\end{document}
```

[image]