# standalone and chemmacros

Tags: formatting, standalone, page, chemmacros

I am using chemmacros to write REDOX chemical reactions. I tried using "standalone" to create a file the size of the equation, but it didn't work.

[image]

how to solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{all}

\begin{document}

\OX{a,Na} $\rightarrow$ \OX{b,Na}\pch

\redox(a,b)[->,red]{ox}

\redox(a,b)[<-,blue][-1]{red}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See, if adding `varwidth` in `standalone` options helps, i.e. `\documentclass[border=2pt,varwidth]{standalone}`

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196514/ ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[margin={-0.5mm 6mm}, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{all}

\begin{document}

\raisebox{1ex}{
\OX{a,Na} $\rightarrow$ \OX{b,Na}\pch
\redox(a,b)[->,red]{ox}
\redox(a,b)[<-,blue][-1]{redux}
                }

\end{document}
```

[image]

- It seems that `bounding box` of this chem expression doesn't consider arrow nor label above/below it, consequently you need to add more vertical space about/below expression.
- Baseline of expression is not at its vertical center. This is in above MWE corrected by `\raisebox`.
- all length are determined by trial/error method :-(