# How to draw this in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I have the following drawing, that I want to somehow replicate in tikz (or similar if that would be easier).

The important part that I cannot figure out is how to have the arrow/semi-cone opening up from the final step (in the circle) to the spectrum at the bottom (running from, in essence, "none" to "full").

[image: Step-to-spectrum]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Can you please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what you have already tried. This makes it much easier for people to help you -- and they are much more likely to help if they can see that you have made a genuine effort first.

Comment: This question is of the type "do it for me" and violates our community's guidelines.

Comment: @Ingo and @ others voting to close, I disagree. This question should be left open. See, for example, [Our Do-it-for-me and Draw-it-for-me comments don't reflect our hypocrisy. Can they be improved?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4267/our-do-it-for-me-and-draw-it-for-me-comments-dont-reflect-our-hypocrisy-can-th)

Comment: Could you please improve the title, to make it more specific.

Answer (score 19):

There you go :

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{penciline}{initial}{
    \state{initial}[width=+\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance,auto corner on length=1mm,]{
        \pgfpathcurveto%
        {% From
            \pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}
                            {\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
        }
        {%  Control 1
        \pgfmathrand
        \pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}{0pt}}
                        {\pgfqpoint{-\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}%
                                        {\pgfmathresult\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
                        }
        }
        {%TO 
        \pgfpointadd{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}{\pgfpoint{0.5pt}{1.5pt}}
        }
    }
    \state{final}{}
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=penciline, decorate]


        \draw[decorate,<-, very thick] (0,1) --++ (0,1);
        \draw (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 1cm) node [align = center] {Final \\ Step};
        \draw[decorate] (-1,-0.85) --++ (-1,-1);        
        \draw[decorate] (1,-0.85) --++ (1,-1);              
        \draw[decorate] (-2.5,-1.85) --++ (5,0) --++ (0,-0.5) --++ (-5,0) --  cycle;
        \draw[decorate] (-2.5+5,-1.85) --++ (1,1) node [above right, align = center] {Spectrum of \\ ant????};  

        \foreach \n in {1,...,45}{
            \draw[decorate](-2.5 + 4.8 - \n*0.002*\n ,-1.85-0.5) --++ (0.2,0.5);
        }

        \draw [decorate] (-7,-3.5) --++ (5,0) --++ (5,0) --++ (4,0);

        \draw[decorate,<-, very thick] (0,1-7) --++ (0,1);
        \draw (0,-7) ellipse (3cm and 1cm) node [align = center] {Final \\ Step};
        \draw[decorate] (-1,-0.85-7) --++ (-1,-1) --++ (-0.3,0) -- (0,-9.5);

        \foreach \n in {1,...,45}{
            \draw[decorate](-2.5 + 4.8 - \n*0.002*\n ,-10) --++ (0.2,0.5);
        }

        \draw[decorate] (1,-0.85-7) --++ (1,-1) --++ (0.3,0) -- (0,-9.5);               
        \draw[decorate] (-2.5,-9.5) --++ (5,0) --++ (0,-0.5) --++ (-5,0) --  cycle; 


    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Source : [Simulating hand-drawn lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines)

Comment: That decoration is lovely. Nicely done!

Comment: I shall cite my source, this decoration is not my work : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines

Answer (score 7):

Here another approach with reusable code and relative coordinates. This way you can reposition your nodes without the need to redraw your arrow-lines with hand.

It hasn't got [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198425/34759) nice pencil-decoration, but it shows how you can reduce your amount of code by reusing parts of it and connect them dynamically.

You can fit the coordinates of the custom arrow easily to your needs by setting new relative coordinates. As the points of the arrow referencing to the circle and the bar (fixed points) are not changed, the position of the nodes can be shifted as you like without loosing the connection between them.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, shapes}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand{\mypic}[2]{
   % 1st param: scope-shift, 2nd param: id for referencing nodes (see below)
   \begin{scope}[shift={#1}]
    \draw node [ellipse, draw, minimum width=4cm, align=center] (circ#2) {Final\\Step};
    \draw [<-, >=latex] (circ#2.north) -- ++(0,.5);
    \node [below=2cm of circ#2 , rectangle, draw, fill, left color=white, right color=black, minimum width=10cm, minimum height=1cm] (spec#2) {};
   \end{scope}
  }

  % Upper pic
  \mypic{(0,0)}{1}
  \draw (circ1.south west) -- ($(spec1.north west) +(.5,0)$) -- ($(spec1.north east) +(-.5,0)$) -- (circ1.south east) ;

  % Lower pic
  \mypic{(0,-6)}{2}
  \draw (circ2.south west) % fixed point
   -- ($(circ2.south west)!.5!(spec2.north west)$) -- ++(-1,0) --
   (spec2.north) % fixed point
   -- ($(spec2.north east)!.5!(circ2.south east) +(1,0)$) -- ++(-1,0) --
   (circ2.south east); % fixed point
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image: rendered image]