# Add annotation on beamer slide, simulating hand-drawing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, annotations

I would like to add on my beamer slides something that simulate as if I had been drawing a comment by hand. This would circle, come on top of text or formulas, and allows to insert text. Ideally, I could use this with the beamer overlay specification, i.e. add it only in a second step. See example below.

Is there anything that could bring me somewhere close to that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Make Titles Informative. }

Iintroduce here two theorems:
  \begin{theorem}
Algebra

1+2=3
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}
2+1=3
\end{corollary}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the `tikzmarks` package. That's what I use for this.

Comment: related `Simulating hand-drawn lines` https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39296/138900

Answer (score 3):

If you got problems with `tikzmark`, here is a pure TikZ solution.

The command `\mypos` has 2 arguments: what to highlight and the name you would like to give to it.
If the numbers are in math mode put `$...$` in `\mypos` first argument.

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mypos}[2]{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=base](#2){#1};}}
\newcommand{\myund}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Make Titles Informative. }

Iintroduce here two \mypos{theorems}{myth}:
  \begin{theorem}
Algebra

1+2=3
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}
2+1=\mypos{3}{mynum}
\end{corollary}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node[draw, red, circle] (A) at (mynum){};
\draw[red] ([yshift=-2pt]myth.south west)--([yshift=-2pt]myth.south east) to[bend right] ++(1,-1) node[red, anchor=west] {Comment};
\draw[red] (A.south east) to[bend right] ++(1,-1) node[red, anchor=west] {Some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

[image]
    \end{document}

Comment: Oh great!!! And it seems using just `\onslide<2->{
\begin{tikzpicture}.....}` makes it appear on slide 2 only, nice!!!

Comment: @Matifou I'm happy you find it useful!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @cfr, `tikzmark` is very useful here. In addition, `decorations.pathmorphing` comes with `random steps`, which arguably looks as if you would have drawn it with your own claws, err, sorry, hands.

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Make Titles Informative}

Introduce two \tikzmarknode{theorems}{theorems} here:
\begin{theorem}
Algebra

1+2=3
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}
2+1=\tikzmarknode[circle,draw=red,decorate,decoration={random steps,segment
length=1pt,amplitude=0.4pt}]{3}{3}
\end{corollary}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,decoration={random steps,segment
length=1pt,amplitude=0.4pt},red]
\draw[decorate] (theorems.south west) -- (theorems.south east)
to[out=-40,in=180] ++ (2,-1) node[right]{comment};
\draw[decorate] (3)
to[out=-40,in=180] ++ (2,-1) node[right]{some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh, that looks very close to what I need! I was not able to compile though, with error message such as *No shape named theorems is known*...  Also, does this work with beamer overlays, i.e. can you use it with \onslide{}, etc? Thanks!!

Comment: @Matifou When was the last time you have updated your LaTeX installation? (There is a new version of the `tikzmark` package, which has the `\tikzmarknode` command in it, could it be that you do not yet have this version?)

Comment: This is what I was suspecting indeed. I ave Ubuntu 18.04, and see a line like:     *tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)* in the `.log` file, does not seem very new indeed... Is there a way to avoid the `\tikzmarknode` function for now? Thanks!

Comment: @Matifou I really LOVE this new function. What precisely prevents you from updating? (My problem is that it is very hard to check if a downgraded code really works because I cannot install the older version of tikzmark easily without spoiling my other TeX documents. On the other hand, you could just download the more recent version from CTAN in your local directory, and I am almost 100% sure it will work. A cleaner way would, however, be to update your *LaTEX* installation, which AFAIK does not mean you need to update UBUNTU.)

Comment: ok, I'll work on updating the pkg, makes sense. For now just copy/paste all files in the tikz pkg, base/tex did not help much, but hopefully I'll sort it soon. Did you geta  chance to see if the tikz could be used with the beamer overlays? That would be aweseome :-) Thanks!!!

Comment: @Matifou Yes, there is even  a special package for that: `beamer-overlay-styles`. Unfortunately I do not understand what you tried.

Comment: oh nice to know abt that! Well I just downlaoded the package from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf and saw a bunch of files in base/tex such as tixk.sty, etc . Copied all of them to the folder where I have the file I am trying to compile, and then ran again. Did not help :-(