# Is it possible to draw a 3d plot as line art with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is it possible to draw a 3d plot as line art with tikz? For example, Is it possible to draw [`z=x*exp(-x^2-y^2)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x*exp(-x%5E2-y%5E2)) with smooth [line art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_art) style? Something like the following figure for `z=x^3-3x*y^2`.
[image]

Comment: This might help to get this started: [Simulating hand-drawn lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39296/4301).

Comment: @Peter Grill: I do not think that the OP is looking for a line style other than normal smooth curves. I believe the question is about drawing just significant lines of a 3d plot as in the example.

Comment: @hpekristiansen: If that is the case then the reference to "line art" style should be removed from the question.

Comment: Something like this: https://eclecticcats.wordpress.com/2014/03/25/tikzpgf-part-2-drawing-3d-shapes/

Answer (score 2):

Asymptote is probably the better tool for serious 3d functions:

[image]

```
import graph3;
size(200,0);
currentprojection=perspective(10,8,9);
real f(pair z) {return z.x*exp(-(z.x**2)-(z.y**2));}
surface s=surface(f,(-1.4,-1.4),(1.4,1.4),nx=20,Spline);
draw(s,lightgray,meshpen=black+thick(),nolight,render(merge=true));
```

If you have a full TeX installation, then it will be already installed.  `texdoc asy` tells you how to run it, and then if you do `asy` to bring up the interactive prompt, typing `help` will open the manual.  It's very powerful but there is a lot to learn.

As the [relevant help page](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/LaTeX-usage.html) will tell you, `asy` can be integrated into your LaTeX source file.