# Is TikZ most appropriate for drawing cartoon for Latex documents? If not, is there any suggestion on which software might be preferable?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing, tikz-pic, software

For example, I wish to draw simple figures such
[image]

or

[image]

and include them as vector graphics in Latex documents

Is TikZ the most appropriate tool to use? Meaning, how difficult/time consuming would it be as compared to some other method. And what other methods are competitive or even preferable to Tikz?

Comment: Although the accepted answer is a TikZ one, I think [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96674) wins. MetaPost is quite good for a "cartoonish" effect or for anything else that requires manipulation of paths.

Comment: If you want to draw this kind of thing manually directly in Ti*k*Z, it could really be a pain. If you absolutely want vector graphics in your documents, then I recommand to do them with an appropriate VG software and export them in Ti*k*Z.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing this type of figures in TikZ is rather complicated.

For example, consider the fantastic [Ti*k*Zlings](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzlings/tikzlings-doc.pdf) package by Sam Carter. This package contains TikZ drawings for various animals, like this owl:

[image]

The basic code for this drawing is (more or less, edited to remove customization options):

```
% Arms %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\owl@part@draw[\owl@body] (0.575,0.8) ellipse[x radius=0.38, y radius=0.1, rotate=-80];
\owl@part@draw[\owl@body] (-0.575,0.8) ellipse[x radius=0.38, y radius=0.1, rotate=80]; 
%
% Body %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\owl@part@draw[\owl@body] (0.595, 0.92) .. controls (0.595, 0.26) and (0.355, 0.18) .. (0, 0.18) .. controls (-0.355, 0.18) and (-0.595, 0.26) .. (-0.595, 0.92) .. controls (-0.605, 1.58) and (-0.335, 2.11) .. (0, 2.11) .. controls (0.335, 2.11) and (0.605, 1.58) .. (0.595, 0.92) -- cycle;
%
% Ears %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\owl@part@draw[\owl@body] (-0.6361, 1.777) .. controls   (-0.6361, 1.777) and   (-0.7586, 1.9603) ..   (-0.6759, 2.2145) .. controls   (-0.3248, 1.912) and   (0.3248, 1.912) ..   (0.6759, 2.2145) .. controls   (0.7586, 1.9603) and   (0.6361, 1.777) ..   (0.6361, 1.777);
%
% Belly %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\owl@part@draw[\owl@body!50!white] (0.425,0.5) .. controls (0.425,0.31) and (0.245,0.27) .. (0,0.27) .. controls (-0.245,0.27) and (-0.425,0.31) .. (-0.425,0.5) .. controls (-0.425,0.81) and (-0.225,0.98) .. (0,0.98) .. controls (0.225,0.98) and (0.425,0.81) .. (0.425,0.5) -- cycle;
%
% head %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\owl@part@draw[\owl@body] (0,1.55) ellipse[x radius=0.7, y radius=0.55];
%
% Eyes %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fill[\owl@eye] (-0.28, 1.6) circle[radius=0.22];
\fill[\owl@eye] (0.28, 1.6) circle[radius=0.22];

\owl@part@draw[\owl@pupil]   (-0.28, 1.6) circle[radius=0.15];
\owl@part@draw[\owl@pupil]   (0.28, 1.6) circle[radius=0.15];
\owl@part@draw[white] (0.25, 1.64) circle[radius=0.03];
\owl@part@draw[white] (-0.31, 1.64) circle[radius=0.03];
%
% Bill %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\owl@part@draw[\owl@bill] (0, 1.4) -- (-0.1, 1.3) -- (0, 1.15) -- (0.1, 1.3) -- cycle;
%
% Feet %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\owl@part@draw[\owl@feet] (0.175,0.2) ellipse[x radius=0.03, y radius=0.1];
\owl@part@draw[\owl@feet] (0.225,0.21) ellipse[x radius=0.03, y radius=0.1, rotate=20];
\owl@part@draw[\owl@feet] (0.275,0.23) ellipse[x radius=0.03, y radius=0.1, rotate=40];
\owl@part@draw[\owl@feet] (-0.175,0.2) ellipse[x radius=0.03, y radius=0.1];
\owl@part@draw[\owl@feet] (-0.225,0.21) ellipse[x radius=0.03, y radius=0.1, rotate=-20];
\owl@part@draw[\owl@feet] (-0.275,0.23) ellipse[x radius=0.03, y radius=0.1, rotate=-40];
```

As you can see this is not easy to make, note especially all the coordinates that need to be set to appropriate values.

Drawing in a vector graphics editor with a graphical user interface is likely to be easier/competitive/preferable for this type of drawing (unless you are Sam Carter or a marmot). Wikipedia has a list on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_vector_graphics_editors that contains many suitable programs.

Comment: samcarter uses a graphical interface too, many of the tikzlings have been drafted in inkscape.