How can I do a sketchy TikZ picture?
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Humor Sans}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations,patterns,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\definecolor{pltblue}{HTML}{1F77B4}

\makeatletter
\pgfset{
  /pgf/decoration/randomness/.initial=2,
  /pgf/decoration/wavelength/.initial=100
}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{sketch}{init}{
  \state{init}[width=0pt,next state=draw,persistent precomputation={
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgf@lib@dec@sketch@t0
  }]{}
  \state{draw}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
  auto corner on length=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
  persistent precomputation={
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgf@lib@dec@sketch@t{mod(\pgf@lib@dec@sketch@t+pow(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/randomness},rand),\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/wavelength})}
  }]{
    \pgfmathparse{sin(2*\pgf@lib@dec@sketch@t*pi/\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/wavelength} r)}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfmathresult\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }
  \state{final}{}
}
\tikzset{xkcd/.style={decorate,decoration={sketch,segment length=0.5pt,amplitude=0.5pt}}}
\makeatother

\pgfmathsetseed{1}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.85}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[xkcd,help lines] (-2,-2) grid[step=1cm] (8,5); % "Karopapier"
    \draw[xkcd,thick] (0,0) -- (0,3) -- (3,3); %zwei Linien
    \draw[xkcd,thick,red] (0,0) -- (3,3); %Linie
    \draw[xkcd,ultra thick, blue] (3,3)  arc (0:-90:2cm); % Kreisbogen
    \draw[xkcd,thick, pattern=north east lines] (-0.4cm,-0.8cm) rectangle (2.2,-2); % Schraffiertes Rechteck
    \node[xkcd, draw, inner sep=0.5cm, fill=yellow, circle] (a) at (2,0) {};
    \node[xkcd,draw, inner sep=0.3cm, fill=red] (b) at (2,-2) {};
    %https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf.shape:border:rotate
    \node[xkcd,draw, inner sep=0.5cm, fill=orange, rotate=30] at (4,-2) {};    
    \node[xkcd,draw, inner sep=0.7cm, fill=green, rotate=50] at (4.5,0) {};
    \node[xkcd,draw, inner sep=0.9cm, fill=blue!40, rotate=70] at (5,2) {};
    \node[isosceles triangle,
    draw,
    fill=cyan!30,
    minimum size =2cm,rotate=40] (T)at (6,0){};  
    \draw[xkcd] (b) to[in=-45,out=45] (a); % Verbindungslinie
    \node[xkcd,draw, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=1cm] (c) at (-1.5,0) {};
    \draw[xkcd,->, decoration={post=lineto, post length=5mm}, dashed] (-0.5cm,-0.5cm) -- (-0.5cm,3.5cm)  -| (c.north);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document} 

The above code is a (slight) modification of an elder answer (Simulating hand-drawn lines) (all credits to @percusse). Today I tried some little experiments with the code; everything looks very "sketchy" as intended except two little things: the triangle on the right-hand side has got a clean outline and not a sketchy one furthermore the hatching in the square at the bottom of the picture looks also "too" clean. Both findings are really nothing to rage about but if these issues could be improved/fixed I think this code could also be used for architectural purposes. Every help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!


Can you please add a screenshot? Thank you

Just added a screenshot.

It seems the blue triangle is missing its xkcd key.

@Teepeemm: Yeah, you are right, now it looks so much better, thanks a lot!!!
