# New command with if/then statement conditioned on non-integer number?

Tags: macros, conditionals

In LaTeX, how do I declare a new command that gives different output depending no the result of a test with non-integer numbers? Specifically, I'd like to a command to compare a number with 0.01 (the numbers would come from a different script): if the number is greater than or equal to 0.01, print `p = 0.45` (or whatever number p is); if the number if less than 0.01, print `p < 0.01`.

I have looked at `ifnumless` in `etoolbox` but it only takes integers and dimensions.

How do I do this with numbers with decimal points? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [`calc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) can help.

Comment: The typical (elementary) approach would be to use lengths. That is, translate `0.05` to `0.05pt` and then perform a length test (like `\ifdim 0.05pt<0.01pt\relax<true>\else<false>\fi`). [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) does provide length tests, and so does other packages. The following seems to be a duplicate: [Conditional using non-integer numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17512/5764) - it handles the same approach of real-to-length usage.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You were almost there... If you want to compare real numbers you have to compare dimensions, so use `\ifdimless` instead of `\ifnumless` like in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\checknum}[1]{%
  \ifdimless{#1pt}{.01pt}{$p < 0.01$}{$p = #1$}%
}

\begin{document}

\checknum{0.45}

\checknum{0.01}

\checknum{0.005}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `l3fp` module of LaTeX3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fpcompare}{mmm}
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\checknum}[1]{%
  \fpcompare{#1 < .01}{$p < 0.01$}{$p = #1$}%
}

\checknum{0.45}

\checknum{0.01}

\checknum{0.005}

\renewcommand{\checknum}[1]{%
  \fpcompare{#1 >= .01}{$p = #1$}{$p < 0.01$}%
}

\checknum{0.45}

\checknum{0.01}

\checknum{0.005}

\end{document}
```

I gave the example twice to show that the comparison operator can be `<`, `=`, `>`, but also `<=` and `>=`. The result is the same because the two final arguments have been swapped.

[image]